# Java class generics

Tags: java, generics, casting

What are my options, if I what the following code to work?

```
class Garage<X>{}

class Vehicle {}

class Car extends Vehicle {}

class Bike extends Vehicle {}

class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Garage<Car> car = new Garage<>();
        Garage<Bike> bike = new Garage<>();
        Garage<Vehicle> vehicle = new Garage<>();
        //what are the options to do this?
        vehicle=car;
        vehicle=bike;
    }
}
```

What I'm after is to try **upcast**(?) car and bike to vehicle. Is this even possible with this kind generic class type?

Comment: the whole reason for using generics is do you don't have to cast. If you find yourself casting you're doing it wrong

Answer (score 1):

In order to do what you desire, you need to change

```
Garage<Vehicle> vehicle = new Garage<>();
```

to

```
Garage<? extends Vehicle> vehicle = new Garage<>();
```